# Get a view into an ArrayBuffer instead of copying

Tags: javascript, performance, arraybuffer

I want to do the equivalent of `ArrayBuffer.slice` without actually copying the contents. The use case is converting a very large (50mb) ArrayBuffer into a string

Below you can see that I am using `new Uint16Array(buffer, start, chunkSize))`. This copies the value from the `ArrayBuffer`, which is slow. Any ideas on how to make this more performant?

```
function arrayBufferToStr(buffer: ArrayBuffer) {
    // Use chunks to not go over call stack
    // chunks of 1024 bytes * 64
    const chunkSize = 1024 * 64
    // To right before the last chunk so the last `String.fromCharCode`
    // can skip passing a byteLength argument 
    const endCondition = buffer.byteLength - (chunkSize * 2)
    let str = ""
    let start = 0

    for (start = 0; start < endCondition; start += chunkSize * 2) {
        str += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buffer, start, chunkSize))
    }

    const view = new Uint16Array(buffer, start)
    buffer = null
    str += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, view)


    return str
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. It looks like you are converting an ArrayBuffer that is encoded as UTF-16 code points to a string. There are APIs like TextDecoder that do that. Also, when passing a buffer to a Typed Array the values are not copied - a view into the buffer is created that uses the same memory location.

Comment: @AndrewAlderson You are right, TextEncoder API is the way to go. The goal I was ultimately trying to achieve was using the Transferrable API to send a JavaScript object from a worker thread to the main thread. Serializing it to a string then parsing the string was the only method I could come up with and I was trying to find an efficient way to do so.